# System freezes on startup

Tags: linux, arch-linux, startup

Lately my Arch Linux desktop freezes more frequently after I boot it up. Now it happens about 4-6 times before I finally get a complete startup. It freezes as different points, sometimes at a message about starting Color Management or Authorization Manager; other times after logging in to GDM or after starting Firefox. If it gets as far as Gnome, I can still move the mouse cursor but all windows are frozen. I can't change consoles or perform anything else with the keyboard except `SysReq+REISUB`. Could it have to do with my CPU needing to warm up? It seems to have gotten worse in the cold weather.

I've asked about the [same issue](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188781) in the Arch Linux forums but wasn't able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted [the answer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1473817#p1473817) to the Arch Linux forums:

> I think the issue is the nouveau drivers. I've switched back to nvidia
>   and it's stable so far. The reason I switched away from nvidia in the
>   first place was that Firefox had some stability issues. But that's
>   better than the whole system freezing, so I'll stick with nvidia for
>   now.